# Make date column from column of continuous month

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like so:

```
df<- data.frame( month= c(rep(1,10), rep(2, 10), rep(3,10)),  
                      div= sample(1:20, 30,replace=TRUE))
```

I would like to make a `date` column where each level of the `month` column is matched with the date. Lets say month 1 corresponds to Jan 2012, and month 3 to March 2012, the resulting data frame should appear as follows:

```
result<- data.frame( month= c(rep(1,10), rep(2, 10), rep(3,10)),  
             date= c(rep("2012-01", 10), rep("2012-02", 10), rep("2012-03", 10)),
             div= sample(1:20, 30,replace=TRUE))
```

I have tried:

```
date<- seq(from = as.Date("2012-01-01"), to = as.Date("2012-3-01"), by = 'month')

my_data<- merge(df$month, date)
```

However, the out put for some reason extend to 90 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(date = paste("2012", month, sep = "-"))

   month div   date
1      1  12 2012-1
2      1  18 2012-1
3      1   9 2012-1
4      1   5 2012-1
5      1  11 2012-1
6      1   2 2012-1
7      1  14 2012-1
8      1  15 2012-1
9      1   5 2012-1
10     1   4 2012-1
11     2  18 2012-2
```

Assuming all subsequent months from 2012-1 are covered, using `dplyr` and `data.table`, you can try this:

```
df %>%
 mutate(temp = rleid(month)) %>%
 arrange(month, temp) %>% 
 group_by(month) %>%
 mutate(temp2 = rleid(temp) - 1,
        year = paste(ifelse(temp2 == 0, 2012, 2012 + temp2), month, sep = "-")) %>%
 select(-temp, -temp2)

   month   div year  
   <dbl> <int> <chr> 
 1    1.    11 2012-1
 2    1.     1 2012-1
 3    1.     3 2012-1
 4    1.    14 2013-1
 5    1.    16 2013-1
 6    1.    14 2013-1
 7    2.     4 2012-2
 8    2.     7 2012-2
 9    2.     8 2012-2
10    3.    18 2012-3
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(month = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3), rep(4, 3),rep(5, 3),
                          rep(6, 3), rep(7, 3), rep(8, 3), rep(9, 3), rep(10, 3),
                          rep(11, 3), rep(12, 3), rep(1, 3)), 
                 div = sample(1:20, 39, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: In this example that would work, but what if the continuous month column extends to 2015, for example? I need  a more flexible solution for variable beginning and end dates. In my actual data set i have 75 continuous months.

Comment: In your data, there is nothing that may indicate year. Or you mean something like the first month in your data is 2012-01 and then after reaching 2012-12 it changes to 2013-01 and so on?

Comment: Correct, in my real data I have simulated data for up to 75 months. I want to use time series analysis which is much easier if I put everything in a date format. Therefore I need to make a column that starts at any date and for each unique month assign a unique year-month designation. Therefore months 1-12 would be Jan-Dec 2012, but month 13 would Jan-2013 and so on.

Comment: I updated my post. However, it requires to have all subsequent months from 2012-1 covered. If some months in some years are missing, it won't work properly.